# Invoice days and amount with Distinct Value

Tags: sql-server, pivot

[image]

I am having a billing table like as above.

I need to get a billing age wise report by using distinct of Branch, UserId, Customer, BillType.

I need to wirte a Stored procedure for getting the following result.

How to write a query for this

[image]

Comment: Hello. How far have you got with writing the query yourself? Can you please post what you have so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the images and add [mcve] instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out the [datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, see below example.

```
select branch, 
       userid,
       customer,
       billtype,
       case when datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) >= 0 and datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) <= 30 then billingamount else 0 end [0 - 30 days],
       case when datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) >= 31 and datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) <= 60 then billingamount else 0 end [31 - 60 days],
       case when datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) >= 61 and datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) <= 90 then billingamount else 0 end [61 - 90 days],
       case when datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) >= 91 and datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) <= 120 then billingamount else 0 end [91 - 120 days],
       case when datediff(d,billdate,getdate()) >= 121 then billingamount else 0 end [121+ days],
       billingamount as total
  from #test
```